# Python NER: add custom text and labels to update the NER model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm using NER to essentially scrub text so that each named entity is replaced with its label (PERSON, ORG, etc.). So "John works at Apple" would become "PERSON works at ORG."

`clause_text` is my list of sentences. I used the ner-d package to build my NER model and scrub text as follows:

```
for text in clause_text:
    input_text = text
    doc = ner.name(input_text, language='en_core_web_sm')
    text_label = [(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc]

    # replace all named entities with their label (PERSON, ORG, etc)
    for text, label in text_label:
       input_text = input_text.replace(text, label)
    scrubbed_text.append(input_text)
```

Now, I am trying to add custom training data. Basically I want to be able to add a sentence with labels and update the NER model to make it more accurate/specific to what I need it to do. Right now I have this:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
    nlp.add_pipe(ner)
else:
    ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
```

```
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer

doc_list = [] 
doc = nlp('This EULA stipulates a contract for Hamilton Enterprises.') 
doc_list.append(doc) 
gold_list = [] 
gold_list.append(GoldParse(doc, [u'O', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'O', u'ORG'])) 
  
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types = ['ORG']) 
ner.update(doc_list, gold_list)
```

But when I run this, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-92c53f5c90b1> in <module>
      9 
     10 ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types = ['ORG'])
---> 11 ner.update(doc_list, gold_list)

nn_parser.pyx in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.update()

nn_parser.pyx in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.require_model()

ValueError: [E109] Model for component 'ner' not initialized. Did you forget to load a model, or forget to call begin_training()?
```

Does anyone have any insight on how to best fix this code, or if there's a better way to add custom entries to update the NER model? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You're definitely on the right track. The spaCy documentation solves your problem with an incredibly clear guide. Check it out at https://spacy.io/usage/training.

I recommend reading the entire post to really understand the API, but the section you'll be most interested in is [Training the named entity recognizer](https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner). It spells out how to add new training data to fine-tune an existing (or blank) spaCy NER model. With code examples too!

Note, they have their training data hard-coded, but if I were you I'd pull that out into it's own pipeline. They also recommend a few hundred observations to get the most effect in fine-tuning.

Comment: Thank you for this resource -- I followed the documentation and it seems like it worked and saved the new model to my designated directory and I can load it as nlp2 = updated model from output directory. However, I'm confused as to whether the new model applies to my code that scrubs text, since my code uses the ner-d package (https://pypi.org/project/ner-d/). Do you have any insight as to how I can get my ner-d code to reflect the new spacy model? Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't see any good reason to use the `ner-d` package – it's simply another dependency that's a super thin API over spaCy. You could do the same this with one extra line spaCy code. However, if you want to stick with it, use spaCy's `nlp.to_disk()` method once you're done training, and then replace your `ner.name(input_text, language='en_core_web_sm')` with `ner.name(input_text, language='path/to/saved/model')`! Hope that works, I haven't tested :-)

Comment: Ahh I see! I did that, but running `doc = ner.name(input_text, language=output_dir)` now gives me `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` -- do you think this has to with the format of the `output_dir` format? (it's a PosixPath to a directory). Thanks so much!

Comment: @Anonymous Ya know, I don't really know. I'm not really familiar with the package and with loading/saving spaCy models. It seems like the module is not happy with being provided with a path. If I were you, I'd explore the source code of both `nerd` and `spacy` to figure out exactly the correct way to load a model. Play around with saving and loading the simplest of models and progressively move toward your NER models to figure out how to do it. Good luck! (if my answer helped, consider an upvote!)